# Interface Builder Terminology

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode7

Have you seen any linking between Interface Builder autolayout and a more deeper level of understanding. Like the terminology between [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nslayoutattribute) 
And Interface Builder

Leading = left etc.

**Update**: Thanks to @skunkmb I was thinking more how Interface Builder settings relate to [NSLayoutRelation, NSLayoutAttribute and NSLayoutFormatOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLayoutFormatOptions). Like when in Interface Builder you can select "Trailing Space to Container Margin".

It is like Interface Builder is trying to make it easier by putting some wording into the UI. But for me as a develop it does not make it easier, I need to know what it is doing - not just experience that something happened and then I just do it over again, when I get in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

## Alignment

- Leading: Left
- Trailing: Right
- Top: Top
- Bottom: Bottom
- Center Horizontally: Center on the X Axis
- Center Vertically: Center on the Y Axis

## Sizing

- Width: Width is a fixed amount
- Height: Height is a fixed amount
- Equal Width: Equal Widths
- Equal Height: Equal Heights
- Aspect Ratio: Keep the same dimensions when scaling (2:1 becomes 4:2)